# How to rewrite URL in wordpress using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to change URL using htaccess in wordpress but still i don't get any solution
 
Here is my current URL

```
http://localhost/demo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-business-card-flyer-designer/includes/wvsd-custom-design-frontend.php?product_id=3270&page=wbfd_design_page&type=wbfd_design
```

I want change this URL like this

```
http://localhost/demo/shop/id-card/internation-card
```

I was try in so many different ways using core php, WordPress function and also other possible option but i didn't get any solution, it is possible to change URL rewrite for this level, if yes then please give me solutions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule demo/shop/id-card/internation-card demo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-business-card-flyer-designer/includes/wvsd-custom-design-frontend.php?product_id=3270&page=wbfd_design_page&type=wbfd_design [NC]
```